# Google Chrome: modifying the source code and sending custom AJAX requests?

Tags: ajax, security, google-chrome-devtools

I just started on dynamic web development and this thought struck me..

As Google Chrome provides `devtools`, we are able to change the source code according to our will.

So just curious... Will I be able to send custom `AJAX requests` to the sever (or run `PHP scripts` in the sever which I'm not supposed to run) to interact with the databases after editing the JavaScript and some HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this technology may help you to make client code do whatever you want it to do.

However note that there's no novelty here. You could mess with JavaScript without live editing.

Not mentioning that nothing like this you need to call a PHP script on server because you just have to know a proper URL for this.

Anyway like most of debugging tools, live editing may provide an additional piece of convenience for hacking sometimes.